# peer to peer vs server client for real time game

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp, p2p

I'm building a game that need real time sync between the users, currently I'm using **tcp** with no delay and its not fast enough.

the game supports 15 concurrent users, the server send the data to the users each 20 milliseconds if it have any thing to send, the data that being sent is max of 400 bytes for 1 user and the others send 30 bytes, the users send to the server their data every 50 milliseconds.

while thinking about a solution i thought why not send the server each user connection data, he will send them back the "others" connection data  and while the game running each user will send directly to all the other users his current information using **udp**.

the second approach is keeping the current server client way and changing from **tcp** to **udp**

what will be faster? and will it make any difference from the current tcp client server speed?

Comment: This question is too broad to answer.  You might think that direct communication between two parties over an IP network ought not to be slower than communication via an intermediary, but different message routing and local network conditions could indeed make direct communication sometimes be slower.  Consider also that for 15 players all to communicate directly with each other, each one needs to manage 14 simultaneous connections, and you may also need some kind of synchronization signal.

Comment: Watchout for NAT! If you send UDP u need to look into [hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching)

Answer (score 0):

UDP will not necessarily be faster in a sense... though it will help speed things up. UDP doesn't consider whether the packet reaches the destination. Instead of waiting for the packet to reach the destination before sending more data, it will keep on sending as fast as possible. If you want a real-time game that isn't turn-based, then you should try UDP.

Comment: ... AND if you can tolerate data loss.

Comment: All real-time games have to tolerate some data loss.

Answer (score -2):

This depends on the type of game.
Usually server client (with UDP) is used because the client is untrustworthy (can be modified to cheat.)

UDP will only be faster if the client or servet has a bad internet connection that drops packets. This is because of the TCP retrying. Please note you will lose data.

Comment: Additionally, communicating via a central server protects players somewhat from metagaming ("I'll launch a DDOS attack on player 2 just as I start my in-game attack"), and better preserves their privacy / anonymity.

Comment: @John Bollinger IP addresses won't be leaked; However the server will need rate-limiting

Comment: How can IP addresses *fail* to be leaked if the players are to communicate directly with each other as the OP proposes?

Comment: @John Bollinger I meant with your solution the IP addresses won't be leaked.

Comment: UDP is actually faster due to TCP always needing to **ACK** all the packets.  TCP max speed is determined by both max throughput and latency. Though this is mostly only true in really heavy transmissions